# Sending Ajax call when a checkbox is clicked in Cakephp

Tags: ajax, cakephp, checkbox, event-handling

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. In a page, I have a checkbox. I want, when I select the checkbox(click on it), an ajax post request will be sent to a page, some data will be saved in the db, and after that a successful notification will appear. And when I deselect it(click on it again), an ajax post request will be sent to that page again, some data will be saved in the db, and after that a successful notification will appear. So, my view file is like this :

```
.
.
.
<form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="item_id" />Save the data</label>
</form>
.
.
.
<?php $this->Js->get('.item_id')->event('onclick',$this->Js->request(array('controller'=>'items','action'=>'saveData',$item['Item']['id'],$another_id),array('async'=>true)));?>
```

In the `saveData()` function :

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
   //save the data in the db
}
```

But, when I click on the checkbox, nothing happens.
I put the php code for the ajax call at the end of that specific view file, not the `default` layout. And, when I see the source code of the page from the browser("view source" option), I don't see any jQuery code that was supposed to be generated by CakePHP.

What is the problem ? What should I do here ? I need to save some data in my db and show some notification.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the Js helper in the controller like

```
public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'));
```

replace jquery with your javascript file.

Also try  including this line just before the ending  tag:

```
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); // Write cached scripts
```

to print the cache.

Comment: Yes, I tried all of this, but same result. By the way, thanks for your help :) .